# How to link the html button to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

how do I connect the button (which is in HTML page) to connect to php url, once the ON/OFF button is clicked. the code basically have to call the php once the button is clicked and when the php is called it need register the ON/OFF to my database along with starting time. can please anyone help me out with this code because i'm new and really stuck. this thing needs to work without javascript or  jquery stuff.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JAYn.jpg

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    h1 {
        padding-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        margin-right:60px;
    }
    </style>
        <title> Washing Machine Control System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BK.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MachineButtons.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body bgcolor = "Black"> 


    <h1>Machine Controller</h1>

        <br></br>
        <br></br>


    <div id="icons"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM1.jpg"  alt="Machine One" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

            <label class="switch">
                <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="M1 On" data-off="M1 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
            </label>

    <div id="icons2"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM2.jpg" alt="Machine Two" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

            <label class="switch">
                <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="M2 On" data-off="M2 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
            </label>

    <div id="icons4"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM3.jpg"  alt="Machine Three" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>
            <label class="switch">
                <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="M3 On" data-off="M3 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
            </label>

    <div id="icons3"><img src="D:\Year 4 (Sem1&2)\Mobile Technologies\Coursework\Website\WM4.jpg" alt="Machine Four" style="width:150px;height:228px;"/></a></div>

            <label class="switch">
                <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="M4 On" data-off="M4 Off"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
            </label>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to solve this in stages.

If you're trying to get the HTML field values to connect to a database via PHP, you'll need to look at your HTML mark up first, as it's not prepared enough to achieve this. Input elements need to sit within form elements in order to initiate a PHP write-to or callback from a database. For example;

```
<form method="GET/POST" action="theNameOfYourPHPFile.php">
  <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" name="washingMachine1" />
<input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" name="washingMachine2" />
```

etc...

Once you've got this all in place, you'll then be able to access the values in the inputs using your php functions in the php file you're pointing the form to. Accessing their on/off values via this

```
<?php $washingMachine1 = $_REQUEST['washingMachine1']; 
etc... 

?>
```

But you'll need more PHP coding practice to take this further. Worth spending some time to learn more about forms and their interaction with PHP via GET and POST methods. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to call a php file from button using form submit and another is submit a form using ajax.

`<form action='url of php file' method="post or get"
.....
....
</form>`

on submit button click form is submited to define by action.

another way

use simple button and on click of button using ajax call a php file without redirect

Answer (score 0):

Use a  before the input fields or the values you want to send and add the php page to which you want to send the input field values in form action and in that php page write the insert query according to your needs.
eg:

Answer (score 0):

I would use `AJAX` and `JQuery`.

Handle the checked events of the checkbox's and when clicked update the value with an `AJAX` call:

```
$('.switch-input').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
   if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      // the checkbox is checked -> update db value
      var data = { 'id' : 1 }; //this is static, instead of 1 use JQuery to get the actual id of the record you want to update.
      $.ajax({
            url: 'update_val.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(result){
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
   } else {
    // the checkbox is not checked
   }
});
```

For more information I recommend you to give a look to the following references:

- [JQuery ajax() function official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- [JQuery checkbox selector official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Hope this helped you :)

**NOTE:** To use this method you obviously have to store your objects' id's so that you can retrieve them when you call the ajax function and pass them via POST or GET to the `PHP` page.